# The difference between "instanceof List" and 'o instanceof List<?>"

Tags: java, syntax, instanceof

I don't see any difference in the following:

```
    Object o = new LinkedList<Long>();

    System.out.println(o instanceof List); 
    System.out.println(o instanceof List<?>);
```

Is there any practical use of `instanceof List<?>` when `instanceof List` can't be used instead and vise versa?

Comment: your &lt; &gt; characters didn't showed up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference. The wildcard is erased at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/mcimadamore/entry/diagnosing_raw_types) blog the answer is 'they are exactly the same':

> as javac forbids instanceof expressions whose target type is a generic type; for casts, the compiler is slightly more permissive since casts to generic type are allowed but a warning is issued (see above). Anyway, the raw type should be replaced by an unbounded wildcard, as they have similar properties w.r.t. subtyping.

```
Object o = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> list_string = (List)o; //same as (List<?>)o
boolean b = o instanceof List; //same as o instanceof List<?>
```